# Interpretation of ROC curve

Tags: roc

I have a ROC curve like the figure below:
[image]

What can be inferred given this kind of curve in general?

What are the differences of states 1, 2 and 3 in the figure?

What causes the diagram to jump straight from state 1 to state 3? Most of the ROC curves on the internet look like the figure below:

[image]

Comment: I gave a general answer. If you could add details about your data (number of samples above all) I could probably detail it some more.

Comment: Probably your model predictions only have 2 values.

Comment: @GeneralAbrial Yes.It is actually a binary classifier. or what do you mean by 2 values?

Comment: I mean that when you present some data to the classifier to make predictions, it gives either A or B as an output, rather than a continuous outcome in some range. For example, logistic regression gives output in (0,1), so any real number between 0 and 1 (such as 0.2, 0.123123, or 0.996) is a legitimate prediction. But your model might only give 0.0 or 1.0.

Comment: @Firebug There exists some 8000 samples. and I have used a SVM (RBF) classifier. 
The accuracy is reported to be 0.5990, precision is 0.5964, recall is 1, F1-measure is 0.7472, and AUC is 0.8248.

Comment: Could you post a small samples of the predicted probabilities? Or perhaps a histogram.

Comment: @GeneralAbrial Yes exactly. It seems to me that  you don't see the plotted curve as something strange or faulty?

Comment: @Reza_Research This outcome is entirely expected when you have precisely 2 unique predicted values. What's strange is that you decided to use a binarization of the SVM output rather than the signed distance from the separating hyperplane as your model output. Use the signed distance to construct the ROC curve and you'll have a smoother curve.

Comment: @GeneralAbrial Now I look at the outputs of classifier. It seems that everyone is classified in Class 1 and no one is in Class 2. According to this classifier!
Is there something wrong? What do you suggest?

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: Class 1 refers to giving up playing a game after some time, while class 2 refers to still playing the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather from the comments that you only have 2 unique predicted values. When you present some data to the classifier to make predictions, it gives either A or B as an output, rather than a continuous outcome in some range. For example, logistic regression gives output in (0,1), so any real number between 0 and 1 (such as 0.2, 0.123123, or 0.996) is a legitimate prediction. But your model might only give 0.0 or 1.0.

Because your ROC curve must go from (0,0) to (1,1) and be non-decreasing, and you have 2 unique prediction values, you can only have 2 points in between. Thus, the plot you have.

Most ROC curves are produced by models that give continuous outcomes. Because there are more decision points, there are more opportunities to measure error rates rates. That produces the kind of ROC curve in the second figure. By way of contrast, for example, logistic regression gives output in (0,1), so any real number between 0 and 1 (such as 0.2, 0.123123, or 0.996) is a legitimate prediction. But your model might only give 0.0 or 1.0.

Comment: @ General Abrial Is my  case considered to be a problem?if so how can I fix it?

Comment: If you're using an SVM, you need the signed distances from the hyper plane. Read the documentation.

Comment: If the output was only {0,1} the ROC would have three points (there are three possible thresholds with only two output values), so that point is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You have four point estimates of sensitivity and specificity. This could be due to really grouped estimates or because you have too few samples.

Answer (score 1):

When calculating the AUC, you need to provide a range of values (as @General Abrial mentioned), not the class labels (0/1)..  so you need to find how to get the non thresholded output from your SVM. For instance in scikit learn you would use *decision_function*, rather than the *predict* function

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html